Could not find a property named 'keyName' on type 'MyClass' on ASP.NET Core OData 8.2.5
Assemblies affected: ASP.NET Core OData 8.2.5
I am getting an error

Could not find a property named 'keyName' on type 'MyClass' on ASP.NET Core OData 8.2.5

but it was working fine up to the ASP.NET Core OData 8.2.4 version.
The exception is raised on this line:
(int)oDataQueryOptions.Count?.GetEntityCount(oDataQueryOptions.Filter?.ApplyTo(myClassQuery, new ODataQuerySettings()) ?? myClassQuery)

mentioned in below code snippet.
Reproduce steps

Create a class, C# Web API as show below.
Call the API with URL https://localhost:8080/api/requests?$format=json&$top=10&$orderby=keyName&$count=true

You will get an exception.
Model
public class MyClass
{
    [Key]
    public int AutoId { get; set; }
    public string KeyName { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

Web API:
public Task GetMyClassData(ODataQueryOptions oDataQueryOptions)
{
    var myClassQuery = dbContext.Table1
                                .GetAll()
                                .Select(t => new MyClass
                                             {
                                                 AutoId = t.Autoid,
                                                 KeyName = t.KeyName,
                                                 Description = t.Description,
                                             });

var response = new
               {
                   totalRecords = (int)oDataQueryOptions.Count?.GetEntityCount(oDataQueryOptions.Filter?.ApplyTo(myClassQuery, new ODataQuerySettings()) ?? myClassQuery),
                   records = oDataQueryOptions.ApplyTo(myClassQuery).Cast()
               };
}

Request/Response
Request:
https://localhost:8080/api/requests?$format=json&$top=10&$orderby=keyName&$count=true)

Response:

Could not find a property named 'keyName' on type 'MyClass'

Expected behavior: it should return valid object
Valid Object should return

ok so since this has worked for you up until the last update, I doubt that this will be it. But is it possible that it gets confused by the Property in the class being named KeyName whilest the url expects keyName? Again I doubt it but its a possibility

Nothing can be reproduced from those incomplete snippets and custom methods. I use ASP.NET Core OData 8 for a reporting site, so I know that's not how OData is used. It's also obvious the fake "repository" antipattern was used, as EF deals with entities, not tables and there's no GetAllAsNoTracking. OData itself will apply all operators and retrieve the count if you just return an IQueryable<TEntity> from a Get() method

If you follow the documented Entity Framework and ASP.NET Core OData tutorials and practices, you won't have to do anything more than add a [EnableQuery] public IQueryable<Customer> Get()=>_db.Customers.AsNoTracking(); action to a CustomerController: ODataController that accepts a DbContext through dependency injection

And if you really need to customize a query, you create an action that accepts ODataQueryOptions<Customer> options and applies it to your DSet or LINQ query with options.ApplyTo(_db.Customers,...). Then you can register the action as an OData function so you can call it from the URL

Hi @PanagiotisKanavos, i have updated the question, I have asked the question in simplest form, GetAllAsNoTracking is the extension function i have created. But the release issue here it seems that we are getting this error when we are passing the Property in CamelCase in the request URL. Like "KeyName" property is in CamelCase in request URL.

BTW following EF conventions means that the ID should be named Id or CustomerId, never AutoId. If you follow the conventions, EF will infer that Id or CustomerId is the primary key of the Customer entity (not table, entity). The entity doesn't care at all how the ID is generated.

@AbhinavVerma there's no EF or even LINQ code in the question, just custom calls. We can't guess why your custom calls fail. If you used EF properly you wouldn't have to write any of that code. The ENTIRE GetMyClassData call can be replaced with only [EnableQuery] public IQueryable<Customer> Get()=>_db.Customers.AsNoTracking();. With just that call, EF itself will apply filters and ordering and execute the Count query if count=true.

@AbhinavVerma  I am by no means an expert on this, but if the problem is passing it in CamelCase, and again I dont know if there is something preventing you from doing so, cant you just ensure that the URL uses KeyName instead of keyName?

@AbhinavVerma (int)oDataQueryOptions.Count?.GetEntityCount( isn't useful either. To get the COUNT(*) of a LINQ query you just call .Count() on it. ODataQueryOptions<T>.ApplyTo() returns an IQueryable, so all you have to do is call .Count() on that query. If you want to retrieve all objects you call .ToList(), not .Cast(). If you want to use paging, you can skip the Skip and Top options just for the count query by passing AllowedQueryOptions.Skip | AllowedQueryOptions.Top to ApplyTo

@PanagiotisKanavos: You are deviating from the main issue. There is no issue with EF core, there is no issue with getting the data. This main issues is when we are passing the Property in CamelCase in the request URL. Like "KeyName" property is passed as "keyName" in CamelCase in request URL then i am getting exception

@SMSTJ: you have got the issue, i have around 20 pages, when I get the response from WebAPI then the in the json response framework by default converts into camelCase and all pages are using the same, but in the latest release version of Odata then why the behaviour is changed? so i was looking for some option to get it fixed

@AbhinavVerma I'm not deviating. ODATA and EF aren't bothered by the case if written properly. That at the very least means the OData model doesn't match EF. I'm writing OData code right now that doesn't require any more than what I posted in the comments. i have around 20 pages and I have 20 reports running over 30M rows producing grid and pivot reports, along with custom formatters converting OData results into CSV and Excel. You're doing it wrong. You can do it correctly, or you can end up rebuilding everything EF and ASP.NET Core do automatically

@AbhinavVerma  hmmm where/how do you generate the request? Another option might be to look at the place where the deserialisation takes place.

@AbhinavVerma if the property is KeyName, why are you using keyName ? Have you tried using the exact casing? You didn't post the OData model configuration so it's unclear what settings were applied or why you don't expect the names to match

Ok so I dont know if you can do this with OData, but maybe you can apply this answer?

@SMSTJ there's nothing wrong with OData. This isn't about serialization at all, quite the opposite. The query parameters were already deserialized into an ODataQueryOptions class. The question's code is unconventional though and tries to replicate what ASP.NET OData itself already does automatically. Property names are NOT case-sensitive, which I just verified by changing the case in my own applications. I'm not exaggerating that all that's needed is just a [EnableQuery] public IQueryable<Customer> Get()=>_db.Customers.AsNoTracking();. That's my actual, working code

@PanagiotisKanavos well thats a fair and valid point, however I do think that its also interesting/usefull to try and find out why the code worked in 8.2.4 but not in 8.2.5

As per Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData 8.2.5 team, they have accepted that there was a bug in the specific version and it will be resolved. For more details :BugDetails
